# Unreachable target error for Pedestrian agents

Tags: runtime-error, simulation, target, anylogic, agent

I'm working with the pedestrian library to create an agent-based simulation. When I run the model, I randomly get the bellow error for some simulation runs or random agents. Has anyone faced this issue before?

Thanks!

> root.worker1s[0].pedEnter.groupAssemble_xjal.?.pedLevels_xjal[0].pedServices[2].queues[0].queue.pedWait.pedGoToInternal:
> Unreachable target: (315.45, 134.11) on level 'name: level' for
> pedestrian 'id: 1' located at: (306.82, 110.05) on level 'name:
> level'!

Answer (score 0):

This happens if there is an unaccessible point in the node such as a column or wall.

Comment: But aren't the Pedestrians supposed to go around the walls? How can I fix the issue? Thanks.

Comment: Yes, but AnyLogic picks a random point within the node. That point might fall within the column you placed.

Comment: To resolve this problem you should draw your polygonal area around a column, this way the pedestrian won’t be sent “inside” it.